# recreate mouse cursor movement in windows by the sensor data and mouse movement based on mobile phone movement in users hand

Tags: python

How to recreate mouse cursor movement in windows by the sensor data and using your own similar sensor reading data to simulate mouse movement based on mobile phone movement in users hand in python.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have given a task for 3 types of sensor data magnetron, gyro and accelerometer as pitch, roll and yaw/azimuth(x, y, z axis of 3d plane for device), but I have no idea that how to do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.